# How to set content in option element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select element and I want to set content in option elements with numbers from 1 to 31 (day). So how can I do this?

Like this:

```
      <select>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          ...
          <option>31</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: @NagaSaiA Sorry. I updated it

Comment: So make a for loop and add them.... Seems like a simple task. Can you show any attempts that failed?

Comment: for(var i = 1; i <= 31; i++){
 $("#option").text(i);
}

Comment: I tried like this but it just shows 31 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var option = '';
for (var i=1;i<32;i++){
   option += '<option value="'+ i + '">' + i + '</option>';
}
$('#days').append(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="days"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your HTML

```
<select id="test_id" name="text_id"></select>
```

In your js use this loop create options.

```
for(var i=1; i<=31; i++){
     var opt = $("<option>").val(i).text(i);
     $("#test_id").append(opt);
}
```

Include jquery in your head section as well